# Customized 'gradient' background in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I found the following slide made using LaTeX, and I'd like to replicate it:

[image]

Specifically, how can I replicate the background? It looks like a transition from a silvery color, to white and gradually back to the original color. **I'd also like to disable themes somehow, and just write directly onto the slides.**

---

Note: obviously the LaTeX code is not available/published. **In addition, the background should not cover the entire slide, but have borders as shown in the image.**

Comment: Still you can cook up a dummy beamer document such that we don't have to type in all the details. And as a personal note, that would look very ugly on many beamers due to low contrast and thin typeface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `background canvas` template to add a shading path with a gray shade on top and on the bottom and white on the middle; something like this (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\shade[top color=gray!85,bottom color=gray!85,middle color=white]
  ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]current page.north west)
     rectangle
  ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%     
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much; your code runs perfectly, and you've replicated the sample exactly.

Comment: When I create a second frame, the background no longer appears, it's just white.

Comment: @user1997744 You need to compile the document twice for the background to be applied.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? It worked.

Comment: @user1997744 because the `overlay` option for `tikzpicture` is used; the first run executes some internal calculations; the second run places the object.